# Froogaloop2 Vimeo video player - start video in full screen

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm using Froogaloop2. 
Is it possible to start video in full screen mode by default? Or start and then 'press' fullscreen button using JS Api?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, it is not possible. The Fullscreen API requires that it be initiated from a user action.